# Zend Framework: Can I use an add view script for editing too?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a simple Zend Framework that has a view script to add records to the database.  This is a silly question IMHO, but how can I use the add view script to edit the record as well??

I have played around with a few scenarios to no avail.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: This depends on how you create the form in your view script. If you use Zend_Form during your edit action you can set the data loaded for the record into the form to set values for all the fields. This should be automatic. If you use static HTML you'll have to re-factor it to load the values from your data set if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Matt S' comment, the method you're looking for is `Zend_Form::populate()`. There are some notes about it in the documentation: [Populating and Retrieving Values](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.elements.values).

Basically, you use it like this in the controller:

```
$form = new Form_Person();
// get the data from somewhere
if($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') && $model->find($id)) {
  // really, use data from the model here
  // but the populate() -method can take any array as an argument
  $form->populate(array(
    'name' => 'Dolph',
    'age' => '52'
  ));
}
$this->view->form = $form;
```

and in your view, as usual:

```
<?= $this->form ?>
```

So the array could be for example the result of `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract::toArray()` with column names matching to the names you gave the form elements.